# vue.js: Tracking currently selected row

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple table where I would like to handle click elements:

```html
<div class="row"
     v-bind:class="{selected: isSelected}"
     v-for="scanner in scanners"
     v-on:click="scannerFilter">

    {{scanner.id}} ...
</div>
```

JS:

```js
    new Vue({
        el: "#checkInScannersHolder",
        data: {
            scanners: [],
            loading: true
        },
        methods: {
            scannerFilter: function(event) {
                // isSelected for current row
                this.isSelected = true;
                // unselecting all other rows?
            }
        }
    });
```

My problem is unselecting all other rows when some row is clicked and selected.

Also, I would be interested to know, it it is possible accessing the `scanner` via some variable of the callback function instead of using `this` as I might need to access the current context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you have only one variable `isSelected` using which you want to control all the  rows. a better approach will be to have variable: `selectedScanner`, and set it to selected scanner and use this in `v-bind:class` like this:

```
<div class="row"
     v-bind:class="{selected: selectedScanner === scanner}"
     v-for="scanner in scanners"
     v-on:click="scannerFilter(scanner)">

    {{scanner.id}} ...
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
    el: "#checkInScannersHolder",
    data: {
        scanners: [],
        selectedScanner: null,
        loading: true
    },
    methods: {
        scannerFilter: function(scanner) {
            this.selectedScanner = scanner;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hi, how about if we want to unselect the row? normally the interaction is to select everywhere except row or double click to the selected row to unselect, how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I was under the impression you wanted to be able to selected multiple rows. So here's an answer for that.

`this.isSelected` isn't tied to just a single `scanner` here. It is tied to your entire Vue instance.

If you were to make each scanner it's own component your code could pretty much work.

```
Vue.component('scanner', {
  template: '<div class="{ selected: isSelected }" @click="toggle">...</div>',
  data: function () {
    return {
      isSelected: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle () {
      this.isSelected = !this.isSelected
    },
  },
})

// Your Code without the scannerFilter method...
```

Then, you can do:

```
<scanner v-for="scanner in scanners"></scanner>
```

If you wanted to keep it to a single VM you can keep the selected scanners in an array and toggle the class based on if that element is in the array or not you can add something like this to your Vue instance.

```
<div
  :class="['row', { selected: selectedScanners.indexOf(scanner) !== 1 }]" 
  v-for="scanner in scanners" 
  @click="toggle(scanner)">
  ...
</div>

...
data: {
  return {
    selectedScanners: [],
    ...
  }
},
methods: {
  toggle (scanner) {
    var scannerIndex = selectedScanners.indexOf(scanner);
    if (scannerIndex !== -1) {
      selectedScanners.splice(scannerIndex, 1)
    } else {
      selectedScanners.push(scanner)
    }
  },
},
...
```